# Disconnect Polygons connected to each other by roads?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, land-cover

I am working with a land cover polygon.  I have a "land" class and a "road" class.  I am trying to disconnect islands in this polygon from each other.  They are connected by roads. Can anyone think of a way to disconnect the islands, without removing the roads from the polygon completely. I do not want to remove them completely, as this would create holes in the islands where a road is. I am trying to avoid having to manually cut the roads out in Editor.  Below is a screen shot of the situation I am talking about. The data set is for a large area. and a couple thousand islands.  I am working in Arcmap 10.4.1

The tan areas are islands (land) the black is the roads connecting the islands.

[image]

Comment: create edit session and split the polygons by their vertices. select individual polygons export into new layer, export that new layer as data then import it back. repeat this for all islands. (one way) maybe not the best but it will work.

Comment: Erase roads from islands. Convert what remains to points. Create TIN, delineate by widest road width. Get triangles, select those that have centroid inside roads. Merge them with islands with holes